# Invalid exception in PIL image library?

Tags: python, exception, python-imaging-library

I'm using the version of PIL from the begin "pillow" package:

```
from PIL import Image
```

When running on Linux (but nowhere else) I sometimes get these very strange errors:

```
Exception ignored in: <function Image.__del__ at 0x7efefc7adf80>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/nix/store/gvv61xmxpdcnm3y7n1xvb0i3h89y7xy8-python3-3.7.9/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3508, in __del__
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

Are there any measures to be taken short of reporting this as a bug?  The traceback gives no clue as to what in my code might give rise to it.

Comment: Can you show us some of your ending code?  The issue here is that you have a Tk object (usually a PhotoImage) that is hanging around and being deleted after tkinter has shutdown.  During its shutdown, it sets the TclError exception to None.  Changing the order of shutdown can help this.

Answer (score 1):

The bug appears when an `Image` is collected by the garbage collector. You can see that the `tkinter` `Image` is composed by the `Image` structure of `PIL` library. So, jumping on the source code for your version of Python 3.7, we see that is on [L3508](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7522ff72484fab740a85f27f2326336906a69674/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L3508)

```py
except TclError:
  # May happen if the root was destroyed
  pass
```

If you go back to the beginning of the file you can see that the `TclError` is from the `_tkinter` module which is generated by C code. So we understand the problem now, the `TclError` does not seem to belongs to normal error from Python that's why it's not a children from `BaseException`.

To be clear, the **bug** is that this error is rejected by Python.

**Note**: there is [only one issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/62341)  that is related to your problem and it has been 9 years ago.

So to answer your question, to document this bug you should make an issue on `cpython`repo if you can make it reproducible. Also, the comment in `tkinter` base code and the issue point a problem of deletion order. So, maybe an angle to reproduce the bug is to figure out when PIL decides to delete the "root" of the `Image` object and, then, the `Image` object in itself. I have no knowledge with this library but the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#important-tk-concepts) can help you out to grasp the concept of hiearchy  of object.

Although, I would advise you to upgrade your Python 3.7 to a more recent version. It may prevent some errors like this. In some months the Python 3.7 won't be maintened ([source](https://devguide.python.org/versions/)).